# Angular limitTo filter's second parameter "begin" does not seem to work in Angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to do a pagenation feature on an array of users.  Using Angularjs 1.3.

```
ng-repeat="user in users | filter: searchText | orderBy: 'lastName' | limitTo:pageSize:startPosition track by user.lanId"
```

I want to use the "begin" parameter, the startPosition variable above, for the start of each page of my list of users.  When that did not work, I simplify the task to just trying to limiting to a array of numbers.

```
$scope.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

ng-repeat="n in numbers | limitTo:2:2"
```

That did not worked either.  That gave me 1 and 2 instead 3 and 4.

Then I switched to Angularjs 1.4-beta.6, and it works as expected for both examples.

My Question:  Is there a way to get this to work in Angular 1.3?  What's causing this in Angular 1.3?

I tried with 1.3.15 and 1.3.2 -- both don't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the documentation the `begin` parameter wasn't implemented in version 1.3.x. See [this](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/filter/limitTo) (1.3.15), and [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) (1.4.0)

Comment: Many thanks ;) I didn't noticed the version differencies

Answer (score 7):

You could always write your own version of limitTo as a custom filter.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('myLimitTo', function() {
  return function(input, limit, begin) {
    return input.slice(begin, begin + limit);
  };
});
```