# How to do pagination with filtering in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angularjs-filter

I'm new to angularJs ,present I'm doing pagination with filtering.In the process I'm getting some problem,when applying filter it giving filtered data but that data is not printing on their respective pages.So please give some suggestions to, how to group the pagination with filtering in angularJs .The following is my snippet.

```
 <div class="col-md-12 form-box pdng-0">
                <select class="form-control2" ng-change="applyFilterOnWorkAuthDrp()" ng-model="workAuthName">
                    <option value="">--- Select Work Authorization ---</option> 
                    <option ng-repeat="workAuth in workAuthArray"  value="{{workAuth}}">{{workAuth}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-box pdng-0">
                <select class="form-control2" ng-change="applyFilterOnPrefEmpDrp()" ng-model="prefEmpName">
                    <option value="">--- Select Pref.Employments ---</option> 
                    <option ng-repeat="prefEmp in prefEmpArray"  value="{{prefEmp}}">{{prefEmp}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <span ng-cloak  ng-repeat="jsList in filtered = jobSeekerList |startFrom:(pageno*pageSize)-pageSize | limitTo:pageSize                                                                      
                                     |filter:workAuthFilter                                                                             
                                     |filter:prefEmpFilter">
            <div class="col-md-12 job-resp-list">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h4 class="job-title blue"><span class="slct-box2"><input type="checkbox"></span>{{jsList.firstName}}&nbsp;{{jsList.lastName}}</h4>
                                                    </div>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
              </div>
            </div>
            </span>
<!--pagination-->
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
           <li class="active" ng-if="pageno>=1"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#page1" ng-click="pageno==1?'':doPagination('back')">Back</a></li>
           <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#">Showing {{pageno}} of {{totalPages}}</a></li>
           <li ng-if="totalPages>1"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#page2" ng-click="pageno==totalPages?'':doPagination('next')" >Next</a></li>
  </ul>
```

### And this is my app.js

```
var jobResApp=angular.module('jobResApp',[]);
```

### Controller.js

```
var jobResApp = angular.module('jobResApp');
jobResApp.controller("jobResController",['$scope','$filter','jobResService',function ($scope,$filter,jobResService){
    $scope.Math=window.Math;
    $scope.pageno = 1;
    $scope.pageSize = 1;
    var count=0;
    jobResService.findJobResponse().then(function(data){
        $scope.totalPages=data.length;
        return $scope.jobSeekerList=data;
    });
    jobResService.getWorkAuth().then(function(data){
        var outputArray=[];
        $.each(data,function(value,key){
            outputArray.push(key);
        });
        $scope.workAuthArray=outputArray;
        return  $scope.workAuthArray;
    });
    jobResService.getPrefEmploymentService().then(function(data){
        var outputArray=[];
        $.each(data,function(value,key){
            outputArray.push(key);
        });
        $scope.prefEmpArray=outputArray;
        return  $scope.prefEmpArray;
    });
    $scope.applyFilterOnWorkAuthDrp=function(){
        var arr=[];
        $scope.workAuthFilter = function(jobSeekerVo) {  
            if(jobSeekerVo.workAuth==$scope.workAuthName){
                arr.push(jobSeekerVo);
                console.log(arr);
                return true;
             }

        } 


    };

    $scope.applyFilterOnPrefEmpDrp=function(){

        $scope.prefEmpFilter=function (jobSeekerVo) {        
            var prefEmpArray=[];
            angular.forEach(jobSeekerVo.prefEmp,function(value,key){
                value==$scope.prefEmpName?prefEmpArray.push(true):prefEmpArray.push(false);
            });
            if(prefEmpArray.includes(true)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        ///$scope.pageSize = 1;
    //  $scope.numberOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.jobSeekerList.length / $scope.pageSize);
        //return $scope.jobSeekerList;
    };

    $scope.doPagination=function(type){
        if(type=='next')
        {
            $scope.pageno=$scope.pageno+1;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.pageno=$scope.pageno-1;
        }
    };
}]);
jobResApp.filter('startFrom', function() {
     return function(input, start) {
            if (!input || !input.length) { return; }
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
});
```

And I am getting data from an external Service the data is in the following form

```
[ {
  "jobSeekerId" : "3",
  "firstName" : "yamma",
  "lastName" : "watson",
  "appliedDate" : "01 May 2017",
  "skill" : [ "10z31 Exchanges", "10 Key" ],
  "prefEmp" : [ "Contract - Independent" ],
  "workAuth" : null,
  "academicInfoVo" : [ {
    "academicInfoId" : 0,
    "courseName" : "Aviation",
    "universityName" : "Amridge University",
    "academicEndYear" : 2017
  } ],
  "annualSalary" : "0",
  "experience" : "0",
  "currentDesignation" : null,
  "lastModifiedDate" : "05-Apr-2017",
  "currentCity" : null,
  "currentState" : null,
  "prefCity" : [ "Los Angeles", "New York city", "San Antonio" ]
}, {
  "jobSeekerId" : "1",
  "firstName" : "richal",
  "lastName" : "sow",
  "appliedDate" : "03 May 2017",
  "skill" : [ "10z31 Exchanges", "10 Key", "1H NMR", "21st Century Skills" ],
  "prefEmp" : [ "Full-time" ],
  "workAuth" : "US Citizen",
  "academicInfoVo" : [ {
    "academicInfoId" : 0,
    "courseName" : "Aviation",
    "universityName" : "Alabama Agriculture And Mechanical University",
    "academicEndYear" : 2014
  } ],
  "annualSalary" : "20000",
  "experience" : "60",
  "currentDesignation" : "Designer",
  "lastModifiedDate" : "05-May-2014",
  "currentCity" : "New York city",
  "currentState" : "New York",
  "prefCity" : [ "New York city", "Houston", "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Philadelphia" ]
}, {
  "jobSeekerId" : "2",
  "firstName" : "2we",
  "lastName" : "surya",
  "appliedDate" : "02 May 2017",
  "skill" : [ "10z31 Exchanges", "10 Key", "5.1 Mixing" ],
  "prefEmp" : [ "Full-time" ],
  "workAuth" : "US Citizen",
  "academicInfoVo" : [ {
    "academicInfoId" : 0,
    "courseName" : "Aviation",
    "universityName" : "Alabama State University",
    "academicEndYear" : 2015
  } ],
  "annualSalary" : "0",
  "experience" : "0",
  "currentDesignation" : null,
  "lastModifiedDate" : "15-Apr-2013",
  "currentCity" : null,
  "currentState" : null,
  "prefCity" : [ "New York city", "Houston", "Chicago", "Phoenix" ]
}, {
  "jobSeekerId" : "4",
  "firstName" : "Satya",
  "lastName" : "Botta",
  "appliedDate" : "21 Apr 2017",
  "skill" : [ "10z31 Exchanges" ],
  "prefEmp" : [ "Contract - Corp-to-Corp" ],
  "workAuth" : null,
  "academicInfoVo" : [ {
    "academicInfoId" : 0,
    "courseName" : "B.A",
    "universityName" : "Andrew Jackson University",
    "academicEndYear" : 2015
  } ],
  "annualSalary" : "0",
  "experience" : "0",
  "currentDesignation" : null,
  "lastModifiedDate" : null,
  "currentCity" : "Houston",
  "currentState" : "Texas",
  "prefCity" : [ ]
} ]
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a [pen](http://codepen.io/)/[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)/[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue). It'll likely get more people to help. Also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422586/using-angular-filter-with-pagination) is a similar question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Angular filter with pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422586/using-angular-filter-with-pagination)

Comment: Use dirPaginate directive.

Comment: @alphapilgrim tq.What ever the example you mentioned  that fulfilled my need.But I am facing some problem it's not grouping the pagination with custom filter (like experience greater than or less than criteria.)

Comment: @alphapilgrim finally it is working fine with custom filter also.But how to wrap no of pages to certain limit like.1,2,3,4,5=====2,3,4,5,6 like google pagination or some other.I'm not aware external directive like Ui-bootstrap.So please give some suggestion ASAP.Tq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solutions.I just implemented pagination along with filters using ui.bootstrap pagination directive and the above commented examples.
This is the documentation I followed

```
 https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/pagination/docs
```

And the below link is my working plunker.I hope this will be help full the 
    people who are facing same kind of problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/plhWxXGSPPtfx1WUSw0o?p=preview