# ng-repeat with limitTo feature with start index

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-limitto

Let us say I have [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] array, I need to split into it so that I always have 3 objects, i.e. [1,2,3], [4,5,6] , [5,6,7] on clicking next in the page. How to achieve this using start index and limitTo feature of angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking against the length of the array in your `ng-click` handler would be the way I'd go about this.

Something like the following:

```
$scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

$scope.startFrom = 0;

$scope.nextPage = function () {
    if ($scope.startFrom + 3 > $scope.items.length - 3) {
        $scope.startFrom = $scope.items.length - 3;
    }
    else {
        $scope.startFrom += 3;
    }
};
```

And then:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: 3: startFrom"
```

If you have any problems with `startFrom` you may need to check your version of Angular. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282082/angular-limitto-filters-second-parameter-begin-does-not-seem-to-work-in-angul) for more info.